# Recursively add Subgraphs to all Nodes in a Graph

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, graph, tree

So, I've a data structure of graph as follows:

```
graph = {'graphData': {'nodes': List of Nodes,
                       'edges': List of Edges,}
         }
```

In addition to that, I've a list of subgraphs as follows:

[image: Subgraphs]

In first step, I add those subgraphs having one node as SOI [3 under Annotation 3] together to form something like this:

[image: SOI Subgraphs]

The following code take care of it:

```
    for coreferanceGraph in unattached_graphs:
        coreferanceGraph = self.merge_entity_in_graph(soi_node, coreferanceGraph, "value-entityName")

        if coreferanceGraph:
            edges_in_coreferenceGraph = coreferanceGraph['graphData']['edges']
            nodes_in_coreferenceGraph = coreferanceGraph['graphData']['nodes']

            for node in nodes_in_coreferenceGraph:
                if node not in graph['graphData']['nodes']:
                    graph['graphData']['nodes'].append(node)

            for edge in edges_in_coreferenceGraph:
                if edge not in graph['graphData']['edges']:
                    graph['graphData']['edges'].append(edge)

            attached_graphs.append(coreferanceGraph)

        else:
            continue
```

What happens in above code is that:
For every unattached subgraph in 1st image, I find if any subgraph has SOI node using function **merge_entity_in_graph()**. If SOI is present in subgraph, the subgraph is returned, and added to original Graph variables of structure defined defined by variables **graph = dict()**.

In next step, I want to recursively add all those sugraphs in Image 1, to be added to open nodes present. In my case, according to Image 2, thats Ec, Ep, E1.

What I expect is:

[image]

Had there been more subgraphs with one of their nodes as **Ef, Eq, Er**, they also would have been added recursively.

My question is, how do I achieve this? I've written a method as follows, but not sure weather approach is right or not:

```
def add_other_subgraphs(self, subgraph, node, all_nodes, graph, coreference_graphs):
    """

    Args:
        subgraph (dict):
        node (dict):
        all_nodes (list):
        graph (dict):

    Returns:

    """

    subgraph_edges = subgraph['graphData']['edges']
    subgraph_nodes = subgraph['graphData']['nodes']

    for node in subgraph_nodes:
        if node not in graph['graphData']['nodes']:
            graph['graphData']['nodes'].append(node)

    for edge in subgraph_edges:
        if edge not in graph['graphData']['edges']:
            graph['graphData']['edges'].append(edge)

    for node in graph['graphData']['nodes']:
        coreference_graph = self.fetch_coreference_graph(node, coreference_graphs)
        if coreference_graph:
            graph = self.add_other_subgraphs(coreference_graph, node, all_nodes, graph, coreference_graphs)
        else:
            return graph

    return graph
```

And the function **add_other_subgraphs()** will be called for each of Nodes i.e. **Ec, Ep, E1**

Comment: "not sure weather [sic] approach is right" signals that you're not ready to post here.  You told us what you expect, but you don't have a complete Stack Overflow posting until you show us what you *get* in a particular case, and perhaps provide some preliminary analysis on the problem.  SO is not a proofreading or testing service.